# Dompdf - Additional page break on table splitting

Tags: dompdf

I have a table which splits into 2 pages and I want to add an additional page-break after the second part of the table to place an image after this table exactly on the new page, not under the second part of the table on page #2. 
Is it possible with DomPDF to add such page-break?

Please don't suggest just adding "page-break-before: always;" to the image div - I need to add this additional break ONLY if the table is splitted on 2 pages.

What I have now:
**page 1**
table-part-#1
**page 2**
table-part-#2
image

What I want to get:
**page 1**
table-part-#1
**page 2**
table-part-#2
**page 3**
image

Answer (score 0):

Put your content page waise in div  and CSS page-break-before/page-break-after properties to create a new page.

see example code.

```
<style>
.page-break {
    page-break-after: always;
}
</style>

<body>
<div class="page page_1">
  page 1
  table-part-#1
</div>
<div class="page-break"></div>
<div class="page page_2">
  page 2
  table-part-#2
</div>
<div class="page-break"></div>
<div class="page page_3">
   page 3
   image
</div>
</body>
```